# rowstyleclass not working on primeng faces version 2

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I got error in rowstyleclass:

> error: Unexpected token 'eq'

I am using primeng 2. Is styleclass format written incorrectly? Please give suggestion

**HTML**

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="dealerDetails.current" [sortMode]="multiple" [rows]="10" 
  [responsive]="true" [editable]="false" resizableColumns="true" 
  reorderableColumns="true" selectionMode="single" 
  (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" class="ui-column-titleLeader"
  [rowStyleClass]="rowStyleClass">

  <div style="font-weight: 900">
    <p-column field="rank" header="{{'RANK' | translate}}" styleClass="table_col_width90px">

      <template let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">

        <div>
          <img src="{{'app/resources/images/Leaderboard Icon/medal icon 1st.jpg'}}" />

          <span style="position: absolute; left: 24px;bottom: 18px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;font-family: fantasy;">{{i+1}}</span>

        </div>

      </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

UPDATE:

After changing `eq` to `===` I get following error:

> cannot read property 'code' of undefined

**ts code**:

```
this.customerService.getDealerDetailsLeaderboard
(this.selectedCustomer.id,this.globalSharedService.getJWTHeaderURLEncoded())
                    .subscribe(
                        dealerData =>{
                        this.dealerDetails = dealerData;

                        }
```

In ts file when I console it displayed the value of `selectedCustomer.code` and `dealerDetails.current.code`

added function

```
    rowStyleClass(){
    if(this.selectedCustomer && this.dealerDetails.current && 
    this.dealerDetails.current.code === this.selectedCustomer.code){
        return 'red'
    };
 }
```

but again the error comes 'code' of undefined

Comment: Are both `value.code` and `selectedCustomer.code` variables? Try using `value.code === selectedCustomer.code ? 'red': null`. If `selectedCustomer.code` should be a string then only replace `eq` with `===`. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: yes object type variable.. now got error: code is undefined @barbsan i will show you the ts file

Comment: selectedCustomer = new Customer(); dealerDetails: any = []; this.customerService.getDealerDetailsLeaderboard(this.selectedCustomer.id,this.globalSharedService.getJWTHeaderURLEncoded())
                        .subscribe(
                            dealerData =>{
                            this.dealerDetails = dealerData;

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, I asked you to [edit] your question and update it (visit link, don't remove your previous code/info). Show more code - where do you assign it, what is `Customer` class and what is `value` - maybe it's the source of error? Are you sure that the error is "code is undefined" or "cannot read property 'code' of undefined"?

Comment: yes that is the error @barbsan

Comment: So which one? answer "yes" for question "Is sth x OR y" is not helpful.

Comment: Do you have `dealerDetails.current.code` instead of `value.code`? What is the structure of `dealerData`?

Comment: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined . this is the error

Comment: i have used value.code because [value]="dealerDetails.current", from dealerDetails i get the code, rank etc

Comment: Does `dealerDetails.current.code === selectedCustomer.code` work?

Comment: *from dealerDetails i get the code, rank etc* - cool, but I asked whether `dealerDetails` is something like `{current: {code: "some code", rank: "some rank", someotherproperty: "someothervalue"} }`

Comment: yes .....@barbsan

Comment: Does your code display the expected data if you remove that whole `[rowStyleClass]`? Does `selectedCustomer` has property `code`? You could try also `[rowStyleClass]="selectedCustomer && dealerDetails && dealerDetails.current && dealerDetails.current.code === selectedCustomer.code"`

Comment: yes. selectedCustomer: new Customer();                                                                 export class Customer {
       code : string;
       name: string;
     }

Comment: check once @barbsan

Comment: now got this error EXCEPTION: this.rowStyleClass.call is not a function @barbsan

Comment: What have you done to get this exception? Ah, seems that I included only condition in that last advice but forgot to return name of class, try:  `[rowStyleClass]="selectedCustomer && dealerDetails && dealerDetails.current && dealerDetails.current.code === selectedCustomer.code ? 'red': null"`

Comment: i did the same but that error occurred @barbsan

Comment: Seems that `[rowStyleClass]` expects a function, try `[rowStyleClass]="setRowStyleClass"` and in ts declare function `setRowStyleClass` that will return name of class.

Comment: see the above code just added @barbsan